# Paginated aggregation with two fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Trying to do an aggregate operation to find distinct property pairs in a collection of objects, and paginated, but the $skip and $limit doesn't seems to work.

I have a collection with the following object type

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "expiration" :  ISODate("2021-06-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "product" : "proda",
        "site" : "warehouse1",
        "type" : "AVAILABLE"
    },
    "quantity" : 2,
    "date" : ISODate("2021-06-28T00:00:00.000Z"),
}
```

I'm trying to find distinct product/site pairs, but only 2 at a time with the following aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('OBJECT').aggregate( [ 
    { $group: { "_id": { product: "$_id.product", site: "$_id.site" } } }, 
    { $skip: 0 },
    { $limit: 2 }
])
```

With `skip` being 0 it returns 2 distinct product-site paris as expected, but when I increase the `skip` value to 2 or more for the next steps, the query will not return anything and I have many objects with distinct product-site pairs that should be returned.

Comment: if you try to skip 2 elements and limit at 2, it's right to return 0 element

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query, it works here https://mongoplayground.net/p/atORWAvelVx just fine. I suggest problem with data. Try to limit to 3 and see if there are more than 2 documents after the grouping stage.

Comment: Notice that the output in that playground is unstable.  In order for skip and limit to give you consistent results, you need to sort first.